# JavaScript ISO Date to human readable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm getting a date like `2014-07-04` in JS, not time.
I want to convert that ISO date to human readable format. For example: `July 4, 2014`

Comment: [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Comment: IMHO, if you downvote a question or an answer, it would be helpful to know why. I assume this question received downvotes because `2014-07-04` is not an ISO formatted date but if that's the case, we should point this out along with the downvote.

Answer (score 9):

Use Intl to format the date. [Check the MDN link for more information about Intl](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

```js
const date = new Date('2014-07-04');
const dateTimeFormat = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en', {
  year: 'numeric',
  month: 'long',
  day: 'numeric',
});
console.log(dateTimeFormat.format(date));
```

Answer (score 1):

The date of `2014-07-04` in your question is not in [ISO format](https://www.iso.org/iso-8601-date-and-time-format.html). An example of an ISO formatted date is `2014-07-04T18:06:08-07:00`. If we want to convert this to `July 4, 2014`, one way is to use JavaScript's Date constructor.

```
var isoformat = 2014-07-04T18:06:08-07:00;
var readable = new Date(isoformat);
```

The variable `readable` now holds the string `Fri Jul 04 2014 21:06:08 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)`. From here, we need to put the month, day, and year in there own variables.

```
var m = readable.getMonth(); // returns 6
var d = readable.getDay();  // returns 15
var y = readable.getFullYear();  // returns 2012
```

Since the month is represented by a number, we define an array of months so we can find the month's name.

```
var months = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"]
```

To get the name, we use the value of `m` to locate the index in the array that we want.

```
var mlong = months[m];
```

In case you have not noticed already, `m` is one less than the number that corresponds to July ( `m = 6` but July is month 7 in a year). This is not a problem, though, because the first index in an array is zero which means index 6 in our `months` array is equal to `July`.

Our last step is to put it all together.

```
var fulldate = mlong + " " + d + ", " + y;
```

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/4h4ss38t/).

Comment: `2014-07-04` is a fully valid date string according to ISO-8601. There is no requirement on time being included. The resource you link to even states so in the first example given.

Comment: It's important to use getDate() instead of getDay() !! getDay will return the wrong day

Answer (score 0):

```js
function humanizeDate(date_str) {
  month = ['January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];

  date_arr = date_str.split('-');
  
  return month[Number(date_arr[1]) - 1] + " " + Number(date_arr[2]) + ", " + date_arr[0]
}

date_str = '2014-07-04';

console.log(humanizeDate(date_str));
```

Comment: Love how slim this code is but I don't think it would work if the string in `date_str` was in an actual ISO format like `2014-07-04T18:06:08-07:00`.

Comment: Doesnt work for ISO dates